# Category Treeview like nopcommerce in MVC 4.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, treeview, nopcommerce

When I click root category, I need child category to be displayed in body with images. Like this:

> http://demo.nopcommerce.com/computers

I have created just a simple tree view in my application:

> http://buy2bargain.com/

Please guide me how to do this. I have created this tree view using recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Edit Category Details: "Include in top menu".